# How to forward TCP/IP packet over UART connecton?

Tags: esp8266, tcp, beagleboneblack, uart

On one end is my ESP8266-01 Wi-Fi module and on the other end is Beaglebone black (not wireless) and ESP module has only UART pins. I want to transfer IP packets over UART line so that I can see Beaglebone as and separate device (probably with it's own IP address).

Comment: Your question is probably irrelevant.  Unless you install custom firmware in that radio module, then what & how you can transfer over its serial interface (e.g. using SLIP) is dictated by that ESP firmware.  FWIW the ESP module is targeted at the MCU market, and is not suitable for SBCs like BBB running Linux.  The ESP module has its own processor & network protocol stack, so it does not work well with Linux as a network interface.

Comment: See http://lwip.100.n7.nabble.com/ESP8266-as-WiFi-to-PPP-Bridge-td28522.html